# after running the Publisher and subcriber, .h file is not being made

Tags: ros, ros-tutorials, header, beginner, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully completed the ROS tutorial till the topic "examining a simple subscriber and publisher". I wrote a simple client and server program. But am not able to make it. The .h file which I am including in the client and server .cpp files is not being generated. How do I proceed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12659/after-running-the-publisher-and-subcriber,-.h-file-is-not-being-made/) by [dip](https://answers.ros.org/users/1656/dip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which .h file?

If it is normal c++ code, you have to write it.

If it is from a message description, you might be missing the `rosbuild_genmsg()` in CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3